# ORA-00936: missing expression using SELECT INTO local_variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to assing a result to a local variable in stored procedure sql.

For example

```
Select c.parm_val from Cusomter.name c where c.id = '102';
```

The above query gives me a result like ***36,1508,4399,4403,4405,4407,4409,4411,4419***

I want to assign it to a local variable
So I created in stored procedure like below

```
DECLARE
values VARCHAR2(500 BYTE);

BEGIN
Select into values c.parm_val from Cusomter.name c where c.id = '102';

END
```

When I execute this I get different errors each time
Something like PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression

I want to assign those result a variable. I don't know if I can use **INSERT** as it not a table.

Can someone help me how to assign it to a variable.

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL but the error message looks like an Oracle message?

Comment: Side note: If `id` is of a numeric data type, you can and should remove the single quotes around the literals.

Comment: The PL/SQL code you posted contains syntax errors. If you haven't already done so, I recommend the Oracle database documentation, in particular the _PL/SQL Language Reference_. Here is a link to the reference for [Oracle 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the syntax you are using. The FROM clause requires a table name like `Customer`, not `Customer.name`, which seems to be a column.

Starting with 11g Release 2 you can use the `LISTAGG` function to concatenate a column from the result rows into a single string.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(c.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.name) INTO "values"
FROM Customer c
WHERE c.id = '102';
```

If `c.id` has a numeric type, drop the quotes: `WHERE c.id = 102`.

---

According to your comment, you probably want something like

```
SELECT c.name INTO "values"
FROM Customer c
WHERE c.id = '102';
```

See: [PL/SQL SELECT INTO](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-select-into/)

Also, `VALUES` is a reserved word in SQL. Therefore, either choose another name, or escape it as `"values"` (in the declaration as well).

Comment: The one that I mentioned above is just a sample data. My original query doesn't have any numbers. To be more precise the query would be like c.id = 'STATIC_VALUE' .....
My whole trouble is around assigning the result to a local variable.

Can you please elaborate more on how to assign the result to a local variable in storedprocedure for SELECT

Comment: The point is that you cannot store the result from several rows into one variable. Therefore you must use an aggregate aggregate like LISTAGG.

Comment: It will not have several rows as I mentioned above the query result will be like ```36,1508,4399,4403,4405,4407,4409,4411,4419```

Let me know if something is not clear

Comment: `SELECT...INTO "values"...` won't work - the variable is defined as `values VARCHAR2(500 BYTE);`, not `"values" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE);` i.e. `values` is not case-sensitive, while `"values"` is.

Comment: Read my last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`INTO` comes *after* the field list:

```
Select c.parm_val into values from Cusomter.name c where c.id = '102';
```